# How to query multiple database in access for my condition

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

Here are my conditions.

I have three tables with following columns

```
Recipe 
   - rID
   - pID
   - ingID
   - ingAmount

Product
   -pID
   -pName

Ingredient
   - ingID
   - ingName
```

for Recpe Table, Recipe.ingID, Recipe.pID is referenced from Product's Product.pID (Primary Key), While the same ingredient.ingID is also referenced from Product.ingID.

In general,

```
Recipe.pID = Product.pID
Recipe.ingID = Product.pID
Recipe.ingID = Ingredient.ingID
```

I want to retrieve following columns using just single query in ACCESS.

pID   |   pName   |   ingID   |   ingName   |  ingAmount  |

I tried following:

```
SELECT Recipe.pID, Product.pName, Recipe.ingID, 
       Ingredient.ingName, Recipe.ingAmount 
  FROM Recipe, Product, Ingredient 
 WHERE Recipe.pID = 5 
       AND (
            Recipe.ingID = Ingredient.ingID 
            OR Recipe.ingID = Product.pID
           );
```

The problem is, `(Recipe.ingID = Ingredient.ingID OR Recipe.ingID = Product.pID)` part gets evaluated first hence multiple rows are queried.

If you got what I wanted to ask please help me.

Comment: Have you tried SELECT DISTINCT? Does that do what you want?

Comment: The condition should be `Recipe.ingID = Ingredient.ingID AND Recipe.pID = Product.pID`

Comment: @Florin: Nope! I want Recipe.ingID = Ingredient.ingID equals to true or Recipe.ingID = product.pID equals to true

Comment: @user995387 When you say "multiple rows are queried", what is the problem, are you getting duplicate records, if so on which field/fields?

Comment: Yeap duplicate records of ingID fields

Comment: Do products and ingredients have to be in separate tables? A box of cake mix and a cup of milk are just ingredients that could be identified with a field: IngredientType. This query would be a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Recipe.pID, Recipe.ingID, Recipe.ingAmount, 
       Ingredient.ingName AS element_name, 
       'Ingredient' AS element_type
  FROM Recipe INNER JOIN Ingredient
          ON Recipe.ingID = Ingredient.ingID 
 WHERE Recipe.pID = 5 
UNION
SELECT Recipe.pID, Recipe.ingID, Recipe.ingAmount, 
       Product.pName AS element_name, 
       'Product' AS element_type
  FROM Recipe INNER JOIN Product
          ON Recipe.pID = Product.pID
 WHERE Recipe.pID = 5
UNION
SELECT Recipe.pID, Recipe.ingID, Recipe.ingAmount, 
       Product.pName AS element_name, 
       'Product as Ingredient' AS element_type
  FROM Recipe INNER JOIN Product
          ON Recipe.ingID = Product.pID
 WHERE Recipe.pID = 5;
```